# Pylint does not work in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I use Visual Studio code as python IDE on Mac, and everything works fine for me. But a couple of weeks ago I've started to use Windows. And suddenly I'm unable to use pylint in the project I've started on Mac.

I have

- explicitly activated pylintEnabled option (=True)
- full path to pylint.exe is set ("c:\Anaconda 3...")
- `pylintrc` file with initial hook adding project to pythonpath (generated by pylint using --generate-rcfile) in the root directory.

With the very same parameters, everything works fine both on Linux (Ubuntu 16.10) and Mac. And does not work on two Windows machines. It seems that the pylint just does not run.

Where did I go wrong?

**Update:**

I've found out that pylint is getting the UnicodeDecodingError:

```
##########Linting Output - pylint##########

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\pylint-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(pylint.run_pylint())
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylint\__init__.py", line 13, in run_pylint
    Run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylint\lint.py", line 1264, in __init__
    linter.read_config_file()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylint\config.py", line 627, in read_config_file
    parser.readfp(fp)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\configparser.py", line 760, in readfp
    self.read_file(fp, source=filename)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\configparser.py", line 715, in read_file
    self._read(f, source)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\configparser.py", line 1012, in _read
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\utf_8_sig.py", line 69, in _buffer_decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

**Update 2**

I'm getting this error using pylintrc file generated automatically. Without this file, everything works fine (except the fact that I can not silence some of the notification, use pylint_flask plugin and make an initial hook).

**Update 3: the propper solution (thanks to the comment of  Elijah W. Gagne)**
This works fine:

```
pylint --generate-rcfile | out-file -encoding utf8 .pylintrc
```

Comment: Looks like on windows you/the editor doesn't save in UTF8 or it saves UTF8 with a byte order mark.

Comment: Python files are in UTF8 by default, aren't they? And even if they are in cp1251 or any another encoding, shouldn't the same error occur on other systems after syncing the project via git?

Comment: Apparently, it works without pylintrc file.

Comment: Python 3 are treated as UTF8 by default. That doesn't force editors to actually save them in UTF8. But the problem seemed to be the pylintrc that was either not in UTF8 or it was a UTF8 with a byte order mark.  So make sure this is actually pure UTF8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have the same issue in Windows, and I get `pylintrc` file by:

```
pylint --generate-rcfile > ~/.pylintrc
```

While I use `notepad++` to open it, the encoding is not `utf8`, and I change it to `utf8`, then it works.

Comment: To remove the need to change the encoding in Notepad++, you can just run: `pylint --generate-rcfile | out-file -encoding utf8 .pylintrc`

Answer (score 5):

By now I've solved the problem by just using a copy of my pylintrc file from mac.
The problem - as far as I understand it - comes from the Windows Powershell.
When I do

```
pylint --generate-rcfile > pylintrc
```

it creates a file with `cp-1251` encoding.

The solution is to copy the data and paste it into an IDE/text editor to save it as `utf-8` file. Or simply (like I did) copy it from another system or from the web.

Answer (score 1):

What I observe, with my `pylint 2.4.4` and `VS Code 1.43.0` at least, is that `pylint` is irrespective to its' `~/.pylintrc` file encoding. I tried it with quite a few encodings (far not only UTF8-BOM, UTF8-noBOM, but few others) - none of them caused it to fail.

The problem, discussed here, in my case was caused that I did not escaped slashes in `~/.pylintrc` file `[MASTER]` section, when defining an `init_hook` it it.

I had:

```py
[MASTER]

# other statements
...


init-hook="import sys; sys.path.append('C:\Users\<username>\Documents\<project>')"
```

and that caused the problem exactly like discussed here.

Once I added a `r` modifier before the path, like this:

```py
[MASTER]

# other statements
...

init-hook="import sys; sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\<username>\Documents\<project>')"
```

it fixed the problem right away.