# Visual Studio Code pylint not working on Ubuntu

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I want to enable linting in VS-Code on Ubuntu 18.04 for python with pylint.
My Workspace Settings look like this:

```
{
  "python.pythonPath": "venv/bin/python",
  "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
  "python.linting.enabled": true
}
```

and my User Setting like this:

```
{
  "window.zoomLevel": 0,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  //"python.jediEnabled": false,
  "kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
  "[python]": {},
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "editor.tabSize": 4,
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
  "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Predawn",
  "workbench.settings.editor": "json",
  "workbench.settings.openDefaultSettings": true,
  "workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": true,
  "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3.8",
  "python.formatting.provider": "black",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

But I'm getting no linting errors when I select `Python: Run Linting`. In my example I would expect the linter to complain about unused imports or variables.

[image: My VS-Code Settings]

Comment: Did you instlal pylint into your virtual environment? What is in the Output panel in the Python channel after you run the command?

Answer (score 0):

I found help in the answer to [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782854/pylint-does-not-work-in-visual-studio-code), although it's related to Windows and Mac.

In my case, I had a hand-crafted .pylintrc file at the root of my workspace and created on Windows (UTF8 encoding), containing

> extension-pkg-whitelist=cv2

Replacing the file by running

> pylint --generate-rcfile > /.pylintrc

on Ubuntu and reassigning my whitelist resolved the problem for me.